# Python: Writing a numpy array to txt file

Tags: python, numpy, fwrite

I have some data in an array with 5 columns and a lot of rows.

I want to save this in a txt file by doing:

```
for i in range(rows):
    with open ('datos_practica.txt','a') as f:
        line=str(data[i,:])
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
```

But instead of getting printing 5 columns in the txt file:

00 01 02 03 04

and so on........

It writes the last column below the first one

00 01 02 03

04

and so on....

Any clues for this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked your code and it does output correctly. Please share the code of `data` and `rows` or just two lines of `data`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code instead:

```
np.savetxt("array.txt", np.array(your array))
```